Move a Linux/Windows setup to a larger SSD
I want to move a dual boot Windows 7 and Linux Mint installation to a larger drive. Right now they exist on a 500GB Samsung SSD. Windows has 289.84 Gib, Linux has 175.42 Gib.
I was thinking of dd or cat the boot/efi partition to the beginning of a new 500GB SSD then dd or cat the Widows 7 partition to right after it. Hopefully leaving the rest of the space on that drive unallocated which I can expand later from within windows.
Then dd or cat the Linux partition to another 250GB drive. All this would have to be done from a live CD.
Then I unplug the Windows/Linux drive and plug in the two new drives and go into the BIOS so I can boot from the Linux drive. Then update-grub and I should have my GRUB boot menu back.
Any ideas on weather this will work? Is there an easier way to give these Windows/Linux installations more space and not lose anything? I bet there would be other people who would want to do something similar since SSDs have become cheaper.

If drive is gpt and UEFI boot then you really cannot use dd for partitions. Gpt has GUID data in primary partition table, partition and backup partition table. They must all match. If you dd one partition then they do not match. There may be ways to repair but difficult. If installing Linux to another drive, better to do new install & restore from backup. Windows 7?, very obsolete.

No need for dd for the EFI boot partition; you can just copy over the file to an EFISYS-compatible FAT32 partition. You would need to update the bootloader list in your computer's UEFI boot firmware, either way.
Afterwards, chances are neither your Linux nor your Windows would boot correctly, since device paths will have changed, even if the bitwise content is the same; so you might need to use a rescue system to restore your Windows boot loader, and you might need to fix your GRUB config or UEFI stub config to boot the correct root partition.
(Generally, using dd has no benefit here; I'd usually recommend you don't. A simple cat /dev/old > /dev/new will work faster, usually, and if you want progress reports, pv /dev/old > /dev/new. Don't use dd if you don't have to!)
Whether or not that's going to be necessary depends on how your boot loading currently is set up, which is a function of what you did in the installer of your Linux distro. This might be super straight-forward (for example, if all devices are referenced by LVM mapper names) and work without touching, it might be slightly more complicated if the root partition is identified by UUID and that changed (wouldn't happen if you just copied the data on block device level).

I got it to work

boot to a live session

dd the Samsung drive over to the 1Tb Crucial (I have this nifty cable gizmo that plugs in to the computer as a usb3 then connects to both sata and power connectors on the drive) Now I can modify the 1Tb drive.

Use KDE partition manager to increase the extended partition to the right. Leave 100G to the right of that for later expansion of the Linux partition. (I probably could have used Gparted but I wanted to try KDE)

Use KDE to move the Linux partition right (to the end of the extended). KDE would not let me shrink (to the right) the extended partition so ......

Use Gparted to shrink the extended partition to the beginning of the Linux partition. This leaves unallocated space on the left of the Linux partition.

Boot to windows 7 (Samsung drive). Use Aomei partition mgr to move the efi partition to the right adjacent to the Linux partition. This leaves unallocated space to the right of the Windows 7 partition.

Extend the Windows partition (to the right) into the adjacent unallocated space. Windows or Aomei can do this. I did it from within Windows.

Boot to Linux Mint (Samsung drive). Expand the Linux partition to the right into the adjacent unallocated space.

Swap out the Samsung 500G and the Crucial 1Tb and it works :)
After I had dd'ed the Samsung drive over to the Crucial I would not have needed to be in the live sesion. I don't remember just when I switched over to the Samsung drive.


I did some backups at various points of the entire 1Tb drive and swapped it with the Samsung to make sure Windows and Linux would still boot. I never needed any of them. As others have said, be careful with dd. I always make double sure of where the output file is going.
